# eclipse cdt relative path to (resource) file

Tags: file, windows-7, eclipse-cdt, relative-path

Eclipse CDT (Juno), Windows 7 (x64), OpenCV 2.4.5

File: haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml is placed in eclipse project directory (where cpp code is).

This piece of code

```
string face_cascade_name = "../haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
```

when build, if executed from cmd or double clicked from file explorer will execute properly.
**But it won't execute if started from eclipse (Run)**. If and absolute path is given, such as:

```
string face_cascade_name = "C:/Users/Nenad/eclipseCDT/PanonIT/Segmentation01e/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
```

Then project **can be executed from eclipse** (and from CMD and double explorer as well).

**How should I setup relative path to allow execution from eclipse?**

Comment: try to add include directory (C++ build settings include) C:/Users/Nenad/eclipseCDT/PanonIT/Segmentation01e

Comment: Yes, it works, but that way it won't be portable, isn't it? What I mean is that it is going to find that path on my machine and nowhere else, correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: When you release your project out of IDE; you should save .xml file to .exe path. Then you can run it properly with "../haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml". But for development purposes, if you want to debug it from the IDE, you should include its path as such. If you want to use relative path, add .xml file not near .cpp file but into the debug folder (or where your .exe is created by eclipse)